# PHP 5.4 getting MSSQL to work

Tags: apache-2.2, php, sql-server

I'm running Apache and PHP 5.4.3. I have a script that uses mssql_connect. When I execute the script I get: **Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()**. I cannot use sqlsrv. I copied the file to ntwdblib.dll and mssql is not commented in php.ini. Any way around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is in PHP5.3+ it was removed. SQLSRV is your only option in a windows environment.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php

Comment: Then I will have to use older PHP I guess, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please see -- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php and ensure you met *all* the requirements. Also, are you sure you are using PHP 5.5.24 because the current latest version is 5.4.x.

Comment: whoops, fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

You need use FreeTDS library. Its simple. Refer to this link: http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP

But library php_dblib.dll for php 5.4 is not found.